# primitive root of a very big prime number (Elgamal DS)

Tags: encryption, signature, prime-numbers, elgamal-signature

For encryption methods there is a need for (very large) prime numbers. So for Elgamal digital signature there is the problem of finding a primitive root of $(p)$ where $p$ must be very large prime number (1024) or (2048) bits length.

My question is: how does the encrypter solve this problem?

I presume a loop to check all the possibilities is an option.

Comment: Dupe https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/54254/how-to-find-a-generator-g-for-a-large-prime-p although the ossifrageal (?) answer is less tutorial than the ursine one.

Answer (score 8):

When considering a big prime $p$, the group of invertible integers modulo $p$ are all integers from $1$ to $p-1$. There are $p-1$ of them. The *order* of an integer $g$ modulo $p$ is the smallest integer $k > 0$ such that $g^k = 1 \pmod p$. Group theory states that the powers of an element $g$, i.e. $1$, $g$, $g^2$... are collectively a subgroup of the group of invertible integers modulo $p$, and the order of $g$ is really the size of that subgroup (called "the subgroup generated by $g$"). The cardinal of a subgroup is always a divisor of the cardinal of the group that contains it. Thus, $k$ divides $p-1$.

A *primitive* element $g$ is one such that the subgroup it generates really is all of the invertible integers modulo $p$, not just some of them. Therefore, to verify whether an integer $g$ is primitive or not, all you have to do is check that its order is $p-1$ but not one of the other possible subgroup orders. That is, you check that $g^{k'} \neq 1 \pmod p$ for all $k' < p - 1$ such that $k'$ divides $p-1$.

The problem can be simplified as follows: suppose that there is a $k' < p-1$, such that $k'$ divides $p-1$, and $g^{k'} = 1 \pmod p$. We can consider $\alpha = (p-1)/k'$, which is an integer greater than 1, and thus a product of some prime integers (since every integer can be decomposed as a product of prime factors). Let's call $r$ one of the prime factors of $\alpha$ (i.e. we write $\alpha = r\beta$ for some integer $\beta$). Since $\alpha$ divides $p-1$, so does $r$, and we can compute:
$$ k'' = (p-1)/r = \beta k' $$
Thus:
$$ g^{k''} = (g^{k'})^\beta = 1^\beta = 1 \pmod p $$

In other words, if $g$ is *not* primitive, then there must be a prime integer $r$ that divides $p-1$ such that $g^{(p-1)/r} = 1 \pmod p$.

This means that in order to test whether a given $g$ is primitive, then it suffices to apply the following test:

> Let $p$ be a prime, and $g$ a non-zero integer modulo $p$. If, for all primes $r$ that divide $p-1$, $g^{(p-1)/r} \neq 1 \pmod p$, then $g$ is primitive, i.e. its order modulo $p$ is exactly $p-1$.

**Now comes the actual difficulty:** you must somehow know the list of prime factors of $p-1$. This is easy if you generate $p$ "specially", as a so-called "safe prime" (the terminology "safe" here is traditional and does not actually imply that the prime is inherently "safer" than any other, but it makes our problem easier). A "safe prime" is an integer $p$ which is such that both $p$ and $(p-1)/2$ are prime. If you generate your modulus for ElGamal signatures are a "safe prime", then there are only two prime factors of $p-1$: these are $2$, and $(p-1)/2$. The test above now becomes the following:

- Get a random non-zero $g$ modulo $p$.
- Check that $g^2 \neq 1 \pmod p$. Note that there are only two integers $g$ modulo $p$ such that $g^2 = 1 \pmod p$, and these are $1$ and $p-1$. Thus, it suffices to choose $g$ greater than $1$ and lower than $p-1$ to fulfill that condition.
- Check that $g^{(p-1)/2} \neq 1 \pmod p$. If that condition is not met, then you must start over with another $g$. Otherwise, that's it, you have a primitive $g$.

No specific value of $g$ is better than any other with regards to resistance to [discrete logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm), so you might just as well try small values of $g$, that offer a small performance boost; you start with $g = 2$ and simply increment it until you reach a primitive value. Exactly half of the integers from $2$ to $p-2$ are primitives, so you do not have to try many times before reaching such a value.

**IMPORTANT:** Take care that the test above is for a "safe prime". In the general case, if given a prime $p$ without any knowledge of how it was generated, you would have to *factorize* $p-1$ into its prime factors, a problem which is, in all generality, quite hard to solve for large integers.

While the ElGamal scheme is nominally defined with a primitive root that generates all invertible integers modulo $p$, it can also be applied to a subgroup, at which point it becomes mostly the same thing as [DSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm). In DSA, it is customary to generate $p$ as follows:

- Let $q$ be a random medium-sized prime (e.g. 256 bits).
- Let $p$ be a random large prime (e.g. 2048 bits) such that $q$ divides $p-1$. In practice, this means that random integers $z$ are produced, and, for each, $p$ is computed as $p = qz+1$, until a prime $p$ is obtained.
- To make an element $g$ of order exactly $q$, a random integer $m$ modulo $p$ is generated, and we set $g = m^{(p-1)/q} \bmod p$. It is easily shown that $g^q = 1 \pmod p$, which means that the order of $g$ is a divisor of $q$. Since $q$ has been chosen to be prime, the order of $g$ can be either $1$ or $q$. If $g \neq 1$, then its order cannot be $1$. Therefore, $g$ will have order exactly $q$ as long as it is not equal to $1$. Probability of $g$ being equal to $1$ is very very small, but even if that happened, then you would just have to start again with another value $m$.

---

**Summary:** to get a primitive element modulo $p$, you get random values and then *check* whether you obtained a primitive element. Primitive elements are not rare, so this works well in practice. However, to do the check, you have to know the factorization of $p-1$, and that is difficult in the general case. Thus, the usual method is to produce the modulus $p$ with a generation method that also lets you know the factorization of $p-1$, e.g. you make $p$ as a "safe prime". Alternatively, you do not look for a primitive element, but for the generator of a subgroup of known prime size (as is done in DSA).

Comment: For the primitive element, what you said is the same as saying $g$ and $p-1$ don't share any prime factors, right?